# ANTLR How to get specific error message when using 2 alternatives in a start rule

Tags: antlr3

I am trying to parse a file that can contain either a table creation script or index creation script.
Below is the grammar. When I run scripts rule with some junk input `create xyz table`
I get an error as `line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'create'`
However when I run table_script or index_script i get specific error message as `line 1:8 missing 'table' at 'xxxtab'`

Is it possible to get the same error message even when I run scripts as missing table or index...?

```
grammar DBScript;
options { output=AST; }
tokens {
    CREATE;
    TABLE;
    INDEX;

}

scripts
:
index_script | table_script
;

index_script
: create index index_name;


table_script
    : create table table_name ;

create
    : 'create';

table
    : 'table';

index
    : 'index';

table_name 
  :
   IDENT;

index_name 
  :
   IDENT;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
INTEGER : DIGIT+ ;
IDENT : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that starting in ANTLR 3.5 the error message <strike>is</strike> *might be* more specific. However, there is no perfect way to report errors for all types of errors. The best tip I can give is telling you that ANTLR is best at reporting (and recovering from) errors appearing in LL(1) decisions, which you can write by left-factoring rules with longer lookahead requirements.

For the example above, you can left factor the reference to `create` as follows. Notice that neither `index_script` nor `table_script` directly reference `create` after the left-factoring.

```
scripts : create_script;
create_script : create (index_script | table_script);

index_script : index index_name;
table_script : table table_name;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer. looking at the whole table and index syntax I think I will not be able to achieve the most granular error messages. I think I would be better off with calling table script and index script individually. Any other inputs?